# Separate legends for subplots in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, legend, subplot

Using matplotlib, I have a figure with subplots. Each subplot is a heatmap generated from a separate numpy array. I want to print a separate legend for each subplot. How do I do that?

In a way, my requirement is the opposite of this question: [matplotlib - Legend in separate subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140311/matplotlib-legend-in-separate-subplot)

Thanks to JohanC for the suggestion. I have two requirements: one is about adding a separate legend to each subplot and also, the legend should correspond to a heatmap. On further search, it looks like the keyword to get a solution is `colorbar` and the following code works for me. It is based on:

[matplotlib colorbar in each subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876588/matplotlib-colorbar-in-each-subplot)
https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)

for i_ax in range(3):
    i_arr = np.random.rand(2, 2)

    im = axs[i_ax].imshow(i_arr)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs[i_ax])
    # axs[i_ax].legend(loc="right")

fig.savefig('mpl_scratch.png')
```

Comment: You might want to add some code to [reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain what you mean by a legend for a heatmap. Having a legend for each subplot is the default behavior. Just call `ax[i].legend(...)` for each subplot where you want a legend.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib) about creating subplots.